# How to get a list of triggered events in espertech CEP

Tags: esper, complex-event-processing

I have implemented espertech CEP in my project and everything works great, however I would like to show a list of all triggered events. Does espertech allow to this?

Comment: What is the use case and EPL statement that you have so far? I'm asking because depending on whether its a pattern, aggregation or whatever you may do the answer may depend. Also what is "triggered events"? Is that output events or events that come in and trigger something or?

Comment: I'm using the UpdateListener to trigger an actions according to the data stream I defined in the event query statement. The UpdateListner works but I want a list of every time its called. For example: when a value is greater than 1 the updatelistener is triggered and prints out the event information. For now i'm talking about simple events

Comment: Ok "a list of every time it is called" means to me some sort of log when the listener gets called, seems like the listener could just log that?

Comment: Yes I also do that but what I'm asking, since the CEP also as table is how to query the CEP engine to give a list of triggered events

Answer (score 0):

By default, CEP does not provide anything as far as I know.

But you can always do it using a `HashMap<String, List<EventBean>>`.

A quick example would be like:

```
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<EventBean>> eventsNeeded = new HashMap<String, List<EventBean>>();
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.addEventType("Event", IEvent.class);
    EPServiceProvider engine = EPServiceProviderManager.getDefaultProvider(configuration);
    EPRuntime runtime = engine.getEPRuntime();
    EPAdministrator admin = engine.getEPAdministrator();
    engine.initialize();

    int limit = 30;
    String query = "Select instanceId, qty from Event where netValue >" + limit;
    eventsNeeded.put(query, new ArrayList<EventBean>());

    admin.createEPL(query).addListener((eventBeans, eventBean1) -> {
        for (EventBean eventBean : eventBeans) {
            eventsNeeded.get(query).add(eventBean);
        } 
    });
    sendEvent(runtime, new Event("X", 10, 1, 100, "A"));
    sendEvent(runtime, new Event("X", 20, -1, 100.0, "A"));
    sendEvent(runtime, new Event("X", 15, 1, 100.0, "B"));
    //You can use eventsNeeded here
```